# Error while importing the Java-1.7 project libraries into Android

Tags: java, android, jar, version, java-7

I've asked a lot of questions the last days, because I couldn't include a .jar-File in my android-project (working with ant).

Today, I switched the Java-Version of this Common-Project to 1.6 and created a new .jar-File.

And noooow, it works!!

Can someone tell me, why Android (2.2) doesn't support Java 1.7?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because when Android 2.2 was created, there was no Java 1.7.

Compare http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history against http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history

Comment: @user1484047 - I don't see how it could have been less misleading.  How is an old Android VM supposed to know that you are trying to use a Java 7 class when it doesn't know anything about Java 7??

Comment: Well... I've marked some attempts as answers but I don't think that this should be normal behaviour... I've asked some very specific questions in ant and nobody had a solution for my problem... Okay, they were encouraged in helping me ;) I'll take a better look for this! Thank you again, you SOLVED my question ;)

Comment: It is not the worst. I have put here some really difficult questions - and as reactions, it happens, no answers at all and sometimes even minuses for the question. So, a real attempt to help is a good deed.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the timeline issue, there is also the issue that Android is not based on the Oracle Java codebase, and hence supporting Java 7 on Android is not simply a matter of porting existing code.

- [Does Android plan to support Java7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535164/does-android-plan-to-support-java7)
- [Java 7 language features with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153989/java-7-language-features-with-android)

Indeed Java 7 adds a new bytecode, so that would entail a change to the Davlik VM to support it.

Comment: So, nobody would rewrite the older Dalvik VMs, that is what you mean?

Comment: @Gangnus - well it is not the point I was trying to make ... but you are absolutely correct.  Something as major as that is highly unlikely to be back-ported to Android releases.  (And it is not in Google or the handset / tablet manufacturers' interest to do that work.  They want to sell *new* stuff.)

Comment: yes. They don't support even *promised by them* Android OS upgrades (Asus Transformer, for example)