# Android: Failed to export application with error -1073741819

Tags: android, eclipse, export, apk

Yesterday, I started having some problems with 9-patch images in Android and Eclipse Helios. To try to fix it, I updated ADT plugin and everything got worse. It seems Eclipse stopped being compatible with ADT.

I stopped being able to export any app. I've tried exporting signed and obfuscated APK, only signed, unsigned obfuscated and unsigned non-obfuscated, always with same result (I copy stack-trace at the end). However, I am able to install the app in my device in debug mode.

More strange, I am able to export signed simple apps such as API demos. Is it possible to get this error due to something wrong in my app? (I've made huge changes since last time I succeed exporting my app, so I can't tell all that has changed)

I increased memory allowance in eclipse.ini. Then, I tried updating everything. I installed latest Eclipse Indigo, ADT plugin and android-sdk, all from scratch. Now, I have latest version of all components, but result didn't change and I keep receiving same error.

Stack trace is as follows, please post any ideas to solve this.

```
eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.7.0
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Error
Wed Feb 01 10:16:02 COT 2012
Export Wizard Error
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Failed to export application
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:258)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.doExport(ExportWizard.java:290)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.access$0(ExportWizard.java:229)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard$1.run(ExportWizard.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: Command-line Error -1073741819
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeAapt(BuildHelper.java:887)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.updateCrunchCache(BuildHelper.java:161)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:131)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.doExport(ExportWizard.java:290)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.access$0(ExportWizard.java:229)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard$1.run(ExportWizard.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using Java 7 which doesn't work well with Android SDK. Use Java 6.

[Java 7 language features with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153989/java-7-language-features-with-android)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that! That's strange because I've been using Java 7 for some time and I've never had these problems. But I switched to Java 6 and it was solved.