# Android SQLite leaked

Tags: android, sqlite

i having problem with sql handler

```
A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/.../databases/queueManager' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

taken from Androidhive tutorial and customized to my use

the table looks like

```
+ ----------------------------------------------------------- +
: DATABASE_ID : DATABASE_QID : DATABASE_QUEUE : DATABASE_DATE :
+ ----------------------------------------------------------- +
```

The code

```
   DBQueue searchDBqid(int id) {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEUE + " WHERE " + DATABASE_QID + " = " + id; 

           Cursor cursornum = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
           int dk = cursornum.getCount();
           cursornum.close();

           if (dk >0) {
               Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_QUEUE, new String[] { DATABASE_ID,
                       DATABASE_QID, DATABASE_QUEUE, DATABASE_DATE }, DATABASE_QID + "=?",
                       new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);

               if (cursor != null) cursor.moveToFirst();

               DBQueue dbqueue = new DBQueue(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                       cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
               return dbqueue;
           }

       db.close();
       return null;
   }

   DBQueue getDBQueue(int id) {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

       Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_QUEUE, new String[] { DATABASE_ID,
               DATABASE_QID, DATABASE_QUEUE }, DATABASE_ID + "=?",
               new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
       if (cursor != null)
           cursor.moveToFirst();

       DBQueue dbqueue = new DBQueue(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
               cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
       return dbqueue;
   }


   public String getAllqid() {
       Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
       today.setToNow();

       String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEUE + " WHERE " + DATABASE_DATE + " = '" + today.format("%d %m %Y") + "'";

       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();       
       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           do {
               if (sb.length() > 0) sb.append(',');
               sb.append(cursor.getString(1));
           } while (cursor.moveToNext());
       }

       String result = sb.toString();
       return result;
   }
   public void deleteDatedDBQueue() {
        Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
        today.setToNow();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEUE + " WHERE " + DATABASE_DATE + " != '" + today.format("%d %m %Y") + "'"; ;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                db.delete(TABLE_QUEUE, DATABASE_ID + " = ?",
                       new String[] { String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0))) });
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
    }
   public int getDBQueueCount() {
       String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEUE;
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
       cursor.close();

       return cursor.getCount();
   }
}
```

Can someone please tell me how to fix this leak ?

full code: http://ijailbreak.me/databasehandler.txt

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Each `Cursor` should be closed when you're finished with it. The traditional way to do this is:

```java
Cursor cursor = db.query(...);
try {
    // read data from the cursor in here
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

But now, with [try-with-resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153989/java-7-language-features-with-android), it can be much more concise:

```java
try (Cursor cursor = db.query(...)) {
    // read data from the cursor in here
}
```

Comment: I also think its because the database is not closed in several of the methods which might mean when his open helper goes out of scope, it leaks, so in my answer I suggest to make the open helper a singleton to avoid open/close issues which will only get worse when he tries to use it across multiple threads :)

Comment: Yes, the database connection should always be a singleton.

Comment: ok, i used this method every time i use Cursor. and added few db.close(); and i think it fix the problem. thanks !

Comment: You may wish to check if cursor is null before making use of it, e.g., `if (cursor != null) cursor.close();`

Comment: @auspicious99 that is not necessary for a database query. It will never return a null cursor. (ContentProviders are different, though.)

Comment: @GrahamBorland Thanks.. on further investigation, it appears you are right, and I had been misled by some sample code that people posted that unnecessarily checked for null cursors for a database query.

Comment: try-with-resources requires api level 19+

Comment: So, when using try construction, the close statement is no longer required?

Comment: Could you please help to solve this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62646206/unable-to-prevent-sqliteconnection-object-leakage)

Answer (score 8):

You forget to close your cursors on several occasions, make sure you always close the cursor when your done.

For instance, the second query does not close the cursor, I have TODO'd it for clarity

Also you do not close the`SQLiteDatabase` once your done in `getDBQueue`, `getAllqid` and `getDBQueueCount`, if you change your design to make your `SQLiteOpenHelper` a singleton then you won't need to close the `SQLiteDatabase` and avoid the leak

```java
   DBQueue searchDBqid(int id) {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEUE + " WHERE " + DATABASE_QID + " = " + id; 

           Cursor cursornum = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
           int dk = cursornum.getCount();
           cursornum.close();

           if (dk >0) {

               // TODO: Close this cursor!
               Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_QUEUE, new String[] { DATABASE_ID,
                       DATABASE_QID, DATABASE_QUEUE, DATABASE_DATE }, DATABASE_QID + "=?",
                       new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);

               if (cursor != null) cursor.moveToFirst();

               DBQueue dbqueue = new DBQueue(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                       cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
               return dbqueue;
           }

       db.close();
       return null;
   }
```

Comment: Could you please help to solve this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62646206/unable-to-prevent-sqliteconnection-object-leakage)

Answer (score 1):

Each time you open a database(readable or writable) and cursor which uses memory resources has to be deallocated by using ".close();" after its usage ends in each database function
eg:

```
 if (cursor != null) cursor.moveToFirst();

               DBQueue dbqueue = new DBQueue(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                       cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
               return dbqueue;
           }
cursor.close();

       db.close();
       return null;
   }

DBQueue getDBQueue(int id) {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

       Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_QUEUE, new String[] { DATABASE_ID,
               DATABASE_QID, DATABASE_QUEUE }, DATABASE_ID + "=?",
               new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
       if (cursor != null)
           cursor.moveToFirst();

       DBQueue dbqueue = new DBQueue(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
               cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
cursor.close();
db.close();
       return dbqueue;
   }
```

and so on....!!

Answer (score 0):

first time open database  and last put this code.

```
 @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         mdb.close();   
         super.onDestroy();
        }
```

Comment: Could you please help to solve this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62646206/unable-to-prevent-sqliteconnection-object-leakage)

Answer (score 0):

```
DBQueue dbQueue = new DBQueue();
```

call your (Database) DBHelper class using dbQueue.getData();

```
 Cursor cursor = dbQueue.getData(); 
 try{
    while(cursor.moveToNext){
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
    }
 }finally{
    dbQueue.close();
 }
```

This is your DBHelper Class

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " (....);
    }
 
 public Cursor getSharedData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from " + "YOUR_DATABASE_TABLE_NAME", null);
    return cursor;
}
```