# Android SQLite database leaked error

Tags: android, sqlite

i having problem with SQLite and i don't know how i can solve that

i don't know if this error can make OutOfMemoryError because i have this error too so please help me to solve this error

```
A SQLiteConnection object for database ......... was leaked!
```

> My database code

```
public class DB_Sqlit extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String BDname = "mdata.db";

public DB_Sqlit(Context context) {
    super(context, BDname, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table favorite ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, img TEXT, url TEXT, num TEXT, size TEXT)");
     }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS favorite");
    onCreate(db);

}



public Boolean Insert_to_favorite(String name, String img, String url, String num, String size) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", name);
    contentValues.put("img", img);
    contentValues.put("url", url);
    contentValues.put("num", num);
    contentValues.put("size", size);


    long result = db.insert("favorite", null, contentValues);

    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}


public List getAllList_Favorite() {
    List<listitem_gib> list = new ArrayList<listitem_gib>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor rs = db.rawQuery("select * from favorite", null);

    if (rs.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            listitem_gib model = new listitem_gib();
            model.setId(rs.getString(0));
            model.setName(rs.getString(1));
            model.seturl(rs.getString(3));
            model.setimg(rs.getString(2));
            model.setnum(rs.getString(4));
            model.setsize(rs.getString(5));

            list.add(model);
        }while (rs.moveToNext());
    }
    Log.d("rewayat data", list.toString());
    return list;
}


public int get_check_List_Favorite(String Title) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor rs = db.rawQuery("select * from favorite Where name like '"+ Title +"'", null);
    rs.moveToFirst();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        int count = rs.getCount();
        return count;
        // do some work with the cursor here.
    } finally {
        // this gets called even if there is an exception somewhere above
        if(cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }

}


public Integer DeleteFav(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("favorite", "id = ?", new String[]{id});
}}}
```

how i can fix this error please ?

And i have question this error can make OutOfMemoryError ?

> database edit

```
public class DB_Sqlit extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String BDname = "mdata.db";

public DB_Sqlit(Context context) {
    super(context, BDname, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table favorite ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, img TEXT, url TEXT, num TEXT, size TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("create table download ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, img TEXT, url TEXT, num TEXT, size TEXT)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS favorite");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS download");
    onCreate(db);

}



public Boolean Insert_to_favorite(String name, String img, String url, String num, String size) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", name);
    contentValues.put("img", img);
    contentValues.put("url", url);
    contentValues.put("num", num);
    contentValues.put("size", size);


    long result = db.insert("favorite", null, contentValues);
    db.close();

    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}


public List getAllList_Favorite() {
    List<listitem_gib> list = new ArrayList<listitem_gib>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor rs = db.rawQuery("select * from favorite", null);

    if (rs.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            listitem_gib model = new listitem_gib();
            model.setId(rs.getString(0));
            model.setName(rs.getString(1));
            model.seturl(rs.getString(3));
            model.setimg(rs.getString(2));
            model.setnum(rs.getString(4));
            model.setsize(rs.getString(5));

            list.add(model);
        }while (rs.moveToNext());
    }
    Log.d("rewayat data", list.toString());
    rs.close();
    db.close();
    return list;
}


public int get_check_List_Favorite(String Title) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor rs = db.rawQuery("select * from favorite Where name like '"+ Title +"'", null);
    rs.moveToFirst();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        int count = rs.getCount();
        return count;
        // do some work with the cursor here.
    } finally {
        // this gets called even if there is an exception somewhere above
        if(cursor != null){
            rs.close();
            db.close();
        }
    }

}


public Integer DeleteFav(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("favorite", "id = ?", new String[]{id});
}






public Boolean Insert_to_download(String name, String img, String url, String num, String size) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", name);
    contentValues.put("img", img);
    contentValues.put("url", url);
    contentValues.put("num", num);
    contentValues.put("size", size);


    long result = db.insert("download", null, contentValues);
    db.close();

    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}


public List getAllList_download() {
    List<listitem_gib> list = new ArrayList<listitem_gib>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor rs = db.rawQuery("select * from download", null);

    if (rs.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            listitem_gib model = new listitem_gib();
            model.setId(rs.getString(0));
            model.setName(rs.getString(1));
            model.seturl(rs.getString(3));
            model.setimg(rs.getString(2));
            model.setnum(rs.getString(4));
            model.setsize(rs.getString(5));

            list.add(model);
        }while (rs.moveToNext());
    }
    Log.d("rewayat data", list.toString());
    rs.close();
    db.close();
    return list;
}


public int get_check_List_download(String Title) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor rs = db.rawQuery("select * from download Where name like '"+ Title +"'", null);
    rs.moveToFirst();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        int count = rs.getCount();
        return count;
        // do some work with the cursor here.
    } finally {
        // this gets called even if there is an exception somewhere above
        if(cursor != null) {
            rs.close();
            db.close();
        }
    }
}


public Integer Deletedown(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("download", "id = ?", new String[]{id});
}}
```

Comment: you need to close your cursors everytime you get them

Comment: can you tell me how i'm new in android and i get this from tutorial

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801602/android-sqlite-leaked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OutOfMemoryError` ? , remember you have to close all the Cursors:

```
public List getAllList_Favorite() {
    List<listitem_gib> list = new ArrayList<listitem_gib>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor rs = db.rawQuery("select * from favorite", null);

    if (rs.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            listitem_gib model = new listitem_gib();
            model.setId(rs.getString(0));
            model.setName(rs.getString(1));
            model.seturl(rs.getString(3));
            model.setimg(rs.getString(2));
            model.setnum(rs.getString(4));
            model.setsize(rs.getString(5));

            list.add(model);
        }while (rs.moveToNext());
    }
    Log.d("rewayat data", list.toString());

    cursor.close();  //*** Add this line!

    return list;
}
```

---

If you are having this message:

> Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly
>   and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

Be sure to close all the cursor in your application.

Comment: i close all cursor and Database  and still same problem

Comment: could you post your logcat messages please.

Comment: 12-02 01:27:25.315: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(20138): A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.kamal.ahmed.rewaya/databases/mdata.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

Comment: " Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed. Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.Be sure to close all the cursor in your application!.

Comment: i edit code and close all cursor see it if something wrong