# android SQLite, can't view data anymore in my listView

Tags: java, android, sql, listview, android-contentprovider

Yesterday I made a nice listView to see my database, but today I tried to add on line to my database and I got an error message saying something like "Database leaked. blabla close your database". After that I could not add anymore line to my database.

But I restarted android studio and I could add new line (and no error anymore) ! BUT I can't see the news lines that I add. I only see my line that I added BEFORE my error (or maybe I can see the one I added that caused me the error). I checked my database with chrome and I see everything, so I really added news lines !

I don't know what is up, I checked my history for several class but I didn't make any bad change (I think). How can I see all my database again ?
I also use a ContentProvider to access my database.

Here is my Fragment class with my list view (I use 2 button inside my elements from my list view and some TextView) :

```
public class ViewCardEditor extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    public static final String authority = "com.example.jean.cartememoire.CardContentProvider";
    public String[] from;
    public final int[] to = {R.id.idList, R.id.themeList, R.id.questionList, R.id.reponseList, R.id.difficultList};
    StockCard stock;
    ViewGroup container;
    ListView listView;
    MySimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup c,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        container = c;
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_card_editor, container, false);
        stock = StockCard.getInstance(container.getContext());
        from = new String[]{stock._ID,
                stock.THEME,
                stock.QUESTION,
                stock.REPONSE,
                stock.DIFFICULTE};

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        if (container != null) {
            container.removeAllViews();
        }
        databaseView(view);

        return view;
    }

    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        Uri uri = builder.scheme("content").authority(authority)
                .appendPath(stock.STOCK_TABLE).build();
        return new CursorLoader(container.getContext(), uri, from,
                null, null, null);
    }
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        adapter.swapCursor(data);
    }
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }



    public void databaseView(View view)
    {
        ArrayList<String> list;
        Cursor cursor = stock.getData();

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        adapter = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(container.getContext(), R.layout.card_stock, null, from, to,0);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        LoaderManager manager = getLoaderManager();
        manager.initLoader(0, null, this);

    }


    public void deleteOneCard(int id)
    {
        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        builder.scheme("content").authority(authority).appendPath(stock.STOCK_TABLE);

        ContentUris.appendId(builder, id);
        Uri uri = builder.build();
        ContentResolver resolver = container.getContext().getContentResolver();
        resolver.delete(uri, null, null);

    }

    private class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter
    {
        ViewHolder vh;
        public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);

        }

        public View newView(Context _context, Cursor _cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(_context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_stock, parent, false);
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            vh.idList = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idList);
            vh.themeList = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.themeList);
            vh.questionList = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.questionList);
            vh.reponseList = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.reponseList);
            vh.difficulteList = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.difficultList);
            vh.Supprimer = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
            vh.Modifier = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonModifier);


            view.setTag(vh);
            return view;
        }

        public void bindView(View view, Context Context, Cursor cursor) {
            vh.idList.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(stock._ID)));
            vh.themeList.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(stock.THEME)));
            vh.questionList.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(stock.QUESTION)));
            vh.reponseList.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(stock.REPONSE)));
            vh.difficulteList.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(stock.DIFFICULTE)));

            vh.Supprimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    View parentView = (View)v.getParent();
                    TextView idList = (TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.idList);
                    /*TextView themeList = (TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.themeList);
                    TextView questionList = (TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.questionList);
                    TextView reponseList = (TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.reponseList);
                    TextView difficulteList = (TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.difficultList);*/

                    int id = Integer.parseInt(idList.getText().toString());
                    deleteOneCard(id);
                    Toast.makeText(container.getContext(), "Suppression de "+id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            vh.Modifier.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    View parentView = (View)v.getParent();
                    TextView idList = (TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.idList);
                    TextView themeList = (TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.themeList);
                    themeList.setFocusable(true);
                    themeList.requestFocus();
                    /*TextView questionList = (TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.questionList);
                    TextView reponseList = (TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.reponseList);
                    TextView difficulteList = (TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.difficultList);*/

                    int id = Integer.parseInt(idList.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(container.getContext(), "bouton Modifier pour "+id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    }



    public class ViewHolder
    {
        Button Supprimer, Modifier;
        TextView idList, themeList, questionList, reponseList, difficulteList;

    }
}
```

Here my class for adding news lines :

```
public class AddCardEditor extends Fragment {
    EditText editTheme, editQuest, editRep;
    RatingBar ratingBar;
    Button buttonCreateCard;
    CardContentProvider stock;
    ViewGroup container;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup c,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_card_editor, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        container = c;
        if (container != null) {
            container.removeAllViews();
        }
        editTheme =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTheme);
        editQuest =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editQuest);
        editRep =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editRep);
        ratingBar =(RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        buttonCreateCard =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateCard);
        stock = new CardContentProvider();
        addData(container);
        return view;
    }

    public void addData(final ViewGroup container)
    {

            buttonCreateCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try
                    {
                        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                        CardContentProvider cp = new CardContentProvider();
                        cv.put(stock.THEME, editTheme.getText().toString());
                        cv.put(stock.QUESTION, editQuest.getText().toString());
                        cv.put(stock.REPONSE, editRep.getText().toString());
                        cv.put(stock.DIFFICULTE, ratingBar.getRating());

                        ContentResolver resolver = container.getContext().getContentResolver();
                        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
                        System.out.println("addDATA DEBUG");
                        builder.scheme("content").authority(stock.authority).appendPath(stock.STOCK_TABLE);
                        System.out.println("addDATA DEBUG2");
                        Uri uri = builder.build();
                        uri = resolver.insert(uri,cv);
                        long id = ContentUris.parseId(uri);
                        System.out.println("addDATA DEBUG3 : "+id);
                        Toast.makeText(container.getContext(), "Carte créé avec succès !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(container.getContext(), "Erreur, echec de création de la carte", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }
            });

    }


}
```

Then my layout for my listView :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeList"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/difficult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/r_ponse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/idList"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/themeList"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/themeList"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Question :"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Thème :"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView6"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
        android:id="@+id/questionList"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/themeList"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/themeList" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/questionList"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/questionList"
        android:id="@+id/reponseList" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/reponseList"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/reponseList"
        android:id="@+id/difficultList"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/reponseList"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reponseList" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/themeList"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/idList"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView8" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/supprimerb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/buttonDelete"/>

    <Button
        android:text="@string/modifierB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonModifier"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/questionList"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonDelete"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonDelete" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my ContentProvider class:

```
public class CardContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
    private StockCard stock;

    public static String authority = "com.example.jean.cartememoire.CardContentProvider";
    private static String path ="Cartes_table";

    public static final String _ID = "_id";
    public static final String THEME = "THEME";
    public static final String QUESTION = "QUESTION";
    public static final String REPONSE = "REPONSE";
    public static final String DIFFICULTE = "DIFFICULTE"; //# = un chiffre
    public static final String STOCK_TABLE = "Cartes_table";

    private static final int ID_STOCK_TABLE = 1;
    private static final int ID_THEME = 2;
    private static final int ID_QUESTION = 3;
    private static final int ID_REPONSE = 4;
    private static final int ID_DIFFICULTE = 5;
    private static final UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    static {
        matcher.addURI(authority, STOCK_TABLE, ID_STOCK_TABLE);
        matcher.addURI(authority, STOCK_TABLE+"/*", ID_STOCK_TABLE);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        stock = StockCard.getInstance(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = stock.getReadableDatabase();
        int code = matcher.match(uri);
        long id;
        Cursor cursor;

        switch (code)
        {
            case ID_STOCK_TABLE:
                cursor = db.query(STOCK_TABLE, projection, selection,
                        selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
                break;
            default:
                Log.d("Uri provider =", uri.toString());
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Pas encore implémenté");
        }

        return cursor;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = stock.getWritableDatabase();
        int code = matcher.match(uri);
        long id;
        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();

        switch(code)
        {
            case ID_STOCK_TABLE:
                System.out.println(values.toString());
                id = db.insert(STOCK_TABLE, null, values);
                builder.appendPath(STOCK_TABLE);
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Pas encore implémenté");
        }

        builder.authority(authority);
        builder = ContentUris.appendId(builder, id);

        return builder.build();
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = stock.getWritableDatabase();
        int code = matcher.match(uri);
        int i;

        switch(code)
        {
            case ID_STOCK_TABLE:
                long id = ContentUris.parseId(uri);
                i = db.delete(STOCK_TABLE, "_id=" + id, null);
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Pas encore implémenté");
        }

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Thank you for help.

EDIT : 
I tried adding a cursor close but it didn't change anything... But I have a button to delete one line in my database and... If I delete one line, then I don't see the line anymore in my listView but I can see a line that I added and could not see before... I think I can only display 3 lines in my listView, so I feel like this is a problem in the listView itself. I'm checking the doc for listView too see what I miss...

EDIT 2 : This is definitely a design problem, I had only a few item show because I could not scroll through all my item. Here is my new fragment layout that contain my listView :

```html
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="layout.ViewCardEditor"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Before, layout_height was set to something like 500dp. But now my listView is little, I can scroll but all my Text View inside my listView are bugged, their content display content from other TextView and change again when I am scrolling. It is like the content from textView is scrolling with me in other TextView.

EDIT 3 : 
I vote to delete my question because I didn't had more error, but I have a new problem with my listView, it has a limited scroll :I can see 3 items and the top of a 4 item, I can scroll just a little bit...

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801602/android-sqlite-leaked . It seems you may have a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to notify `Cursors` that the content has changed using [ContentResolvers.notifyChange(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange(android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver)) method. You'll want to do this in your custom ContentProvider when you update data. This call allows Cursors that register for change notifications to refresh their data.